# Extending a question on a subset of transpose matrices and linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918346/question-on-a-set-of-transpose-matrices-and-linear-independence), which appears in the text: Linear Algebra by Friedberg, Insel, and Spence, asks ``prove that if $\{A_{1},A_{2},\dots,A_{k}\}$ is a linearly independent subset of $M_{n\times n}(F),$ then $\{A_{1}^{t},A_{2}^{t},\dots,A_{k}^{t}\}$ is also linearly independent.''

Can the statement be rephrased as an if and only if? Namely, prove that $\{A_{1},A_{2},\dots,A_{k}\}$ is a linearly independent subset of $M_{n\times n}(F)$ if and only if $\{A_{1}^{t},A_{2}^{t},\dots,A_{k}^{t}\}$ is a linearly independent subset of $M_{n\times n}(F).$

I believe this is the case, as the previous [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918346/question-on-a-set-of-transpose-matrices-and-linear-independence) shows one direction. Then, the other direction follows, if we suppose $\{A_{1}^{t},A_{2}^{t},\dots,A_{k}^{t}\}$ is a linearly independent subset of $M_{n\times n}(F).$ Namely, suppose $0 = \sum_{i=1}^{k}a_{i}A_{i},$ where $a_{i} \in F$ for $i=1,\dots,k.$ Then, $0 = (\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_{i}A_{i})^{t} = \sum_{i=1}^{k}a_{i}A_{i}^{t}$ implies $a_{1}=\cdots=a_{k}=0.$ Hence, $\{A_{1},A_{2},\dots,A_{k}\}$ is a linearly independent subset of $M_{n\times n}(F).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer goes in both directions because $(A^t)^t=A$. More precisely, if $\{A_1^t,\cdots,A_k^t\}$ are linearly independent then we use the fact already shown in the first direction to show that the set transpose matrices $\{(A_1^t)^t,\cdots,(A_k^t)^t\}$
is lienarly independent.

Now remember that $\{(A_1^t)^t,\cdots,(A_k^t)^t\}=\{A_1,\cdots,A_k\}$.